# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xxid'

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I have been getting the below errors for trying to open a file with xlsx extension.

```
import pandas as pd 
readFile = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
```

Error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1419, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 525, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 518, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 536, in load_workbook
    return load_workbook(
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 317, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 281, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 198, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/styles/stylesheet.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 87, in from_tree
    obj = desc.expected_type.from_tree(el)
  File "/Users/dummy/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'xxid'
```

NB:
I found a hack around reading this file. I open the file with my Excel on my pc and I do a Ctrl+S. After that, it works fine. But it can be very exhausting when I'm trying to work with over 100 files.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: try different engines while reading excel.

Comment: got the same error and ctrl+s fix it. why ?